# Aligning matrices vertically as well as horizontally in LaTeX

Tags: math, latex, vertical-alignment, alignment

I'm trying to accomplish this in LaTeX:

```
⎡a⎤ ⎡b …  n⎤
⎢⁞⎢ ⎢⁞ ⋱ ⁞⎢
⎣x⎦ ⎣y …  z⎦

      [a  … x]
```

I'm able to get a vector + a matrix on one line, but I'm not sure how to align the vector below so that it sits perfectly under the large matrix.

Here's a less-unicode text representation of the 'drawing' above:

```
[a] [ b c ]
[d] [ e f ]
    [ g h ]
```

Note that the last line ([ g h ]) is a single-row matrix, separate from the 2x2 matrix above it.

Comment: Could you use more ASCII and less Unicode characters? I don't know about others, but here your example is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\edit2
**final answer:**

```
\begin{align*}
        \begin{vmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{vmatrix} &\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 \end{vmatrix} \\[6px]
        &\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}
```

does exactly what you want, read below for more info about placement and such. The "&" sign is used to align in general. Forgot the first line had 2 matrices but now you have it :).

**info on spacing and such**
    \begin{align*}
            &\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \ 3 & 4 & 5 \end{pmatrix} \[6px]
            &\hspace{2px}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} 
    \end{align*}

would do the job. For some strange reason the align gave errors when leaving out the first "&" symbol and it gave a 2px offset. I figured you wanted some space between the two if not leave the [6px]. You can always use **\hspace{amount of whitespace}** to place your second matrix in the place you want. This can be given in pt's, px's (which i did) etc.

//edit
Hm I notice the \hspace{} is actually not needed, but can be used in case of **pmatrix**. What happens is that the pmatrix brackets give a biased image of the matrices. When using **vmatrix** like:

```
\begin{align*}
        &\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 \end{vmatrix} \\[6px]
        &\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}
```

It all goes well :). So basically, probably the easiest way to fix it is either use other brackets to make it look good or use the \hspace to align as you like it.

Comment: Actually since your example only contains single character long entries, they are easy to align, also the question did give this example so that's fine. But what if one of the entries in the matrix was a `2+10` instead of just being a `2`. This shows that the lower row vector isn't properly aligned with the matrix, it just has it's left end aligned. Do you know some way the two can have their columns aligned properly in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html) can do this.  See [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the thing in `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` and use `&` as the alignment marker in your formulas.

Example:

`\begin{align*}
        \begin{pmatrix} ... vector here \end{pmatrix}
        &\begin{pmatrix} ... first matrix here \end{pmatrix}\\
        &\begin{pmatrix} ... second matrix here \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}`

Comment: can't check at the moment but I think this gives some errors.